# jquery if div id has children

Tags: jquery, children

This `if`-condition is what's giving me trouble:

```
if (div id=myfav has children) {
   do something
} else {
   do something else 
}
```

I tried all the following:

```
if ( $('#myfav:hasChildren') ) { do something }
if ( $('#myfav').children() ) { do something }
if ( $('#myfav:empty') ) { do something }
if ( $('#myfav:not(:has(*))') ) { do something }
```

Answer (score 509, accepted):

```
if ( $('#myfav').children().length > 0 ) {
     // do something
}
```

This should work. The `children()` function returns a JQuery object that contains the children. So you just need to check the size and see if it has at least one child.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is is what worked for me. I knew I was on the right track with the .children(), but didn't know what was wrong with it. Apparently size could be 0, makes sense.

Comment: If you add a selector to children, you can also check if an element has children that match a particular selector, like if you want to see if an element has a child of a particular class.

Comment: minor issue. don't mean to nitpick but `children().length` should be called instead of size() per jQuery docs here: http://api.jquery.com/size

Comment: And what if the node only contains text!?

Comment: @sirwilliam The node will return with 0 length.

Answer (score 58):

This snippet will determine if the element has children using the [`:parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/) selector:

```
if ($('#myfav').is(':parent')) {
    // do something
}
```

Note that `:parent` also considers an element with one or more text nodes to be a parent.

Thus the `div` elements in `<div>some text</div>` and `<div><span>some text</span></div>` will each be considered a parent but `<div></div>` is not a parent.

Comment: +1 for the informative explanation, although it didn't work out for me since my code is one of those exceptions where I do have spaces and new lines remnants of old removes. Good info though.

Comment: Yes, I think this answer is more elegant than S Pangborn's. Both are completely legit though.

Comment: I know this is old, but would `($('#myfav :parent').length > 0)` be faster?  I find yours more readable so it probably isn't worth the trade off in most situations.

Comment: @Milo LaMar, I'd suspect there isn't much of a performance difference, but the only way to be sure is to try it! Also, you'd have to remove the space between `#myfav` and `:parent` in your example, otherwise the selector isn't the same as what my answer would provide.

Comment: A very small amount of reading answered enough for me. Taken from http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/ `Additional Notes:
Because :parent is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :parent cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. To achieve the best performance when using :parent to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":parent").`

Comment: performance test results in 0.002s - i prefer this way, because it's best readable...

Comment: I'm confused, isn't this the best answer?

Comment: **Important note:** the `:parent` selector takes into account any text nodes -- ***which includes white space*** -- so `.is(':parent')` is true if you had a single space, like `<div> </div>`.

Answer (score 49):

Another option, just for the heck of it would be:

```
if ( $('#myFav > *').length > 0 ) {
     // do something
}
```

May actually be the fastest since it strictly uses the Sizzle engine and not necessarily any jQuery, as it were. Could be wrong though. Nevertheless, it works.

Answer (score 17):

You can also check whether div has specific children or not,

```
if($('#myDiv').has('select').length>0)
{
   // Do something here.
   console.log("you can log here");

}
```

Answer (score 16):

There's actually quite a simple native method for this:

```
if( $('#myfav')[0].hasChildNodes() ) { ... }
```

Note that this also includes simple text nodes, so it will be true for a `<div>text</div>`.

Comment: `$(...)[0] is undefined` this may happen if `#myfav` is not found. I'd test the existence of the first matched element prior to apply that condition, i.e.: `$('#myfav')[0] && $('#myfav')[0].hasChildNodes()`.

Answer (score 16):

and if you want to check div has a perticular children(say `<p>` use:

```
if ($('#myfav').children('p').length > 0) {
     // do something
}
```

Answer (score 8):

## The jQuery way

In jQuery, you can use `$('#id').children().length > 0` to test if an element has children.

#### Demo

```js
var test1 = $('#test');
var test2 = $('#test2');

if(test1.children().length > 0) {
    test1.addClass('success');
} else {
    test1.addClass('failure');
}

if(test2.children().length > 0) {
    test2.addClass('success');
} else {
    test2.addClass('failure');
}
```

```css
.success {
    background: #9f9;
}

.failure {
    background: #f99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
   <span>Children</span>
</div>
<div id="test2">
   No children
</div>
```

---

## The vanilla JS way

If you don't want to use jQuery, you can use `document.getElementById('id').children.length > 0` to test if an element has children.

#### Demo

```js
var test1 = document.getElementById('test');
var test2 = document.getElementById('test2');

if(test1.children.length > 0) {
    test1.classList.add('success');
} else {
    test1.classList.add('failure');
}

if(test2.children.length > 0) {
    test2.classList.add('success');
} else {
    test2.classList.add('failure');
}
```

```css
.success {
    background: #9f9;
}

.failure {
    background: #f99;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
   <span>Children</span>
</div>
<div id="test2">
   No children
</div>
```