# jquery: if ul is empty

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, html-lists

Okay I have a jQuery dialog box which has a form in it and I am at my wits end trying to figure this out... Lets see if I can verbalize what I am trying to do..

I have 3 text boxes.  `#apInterest`, `#apPayment` and `#apPrincipal` in that exact order.

basic english terms of what i am trying to do:

on keyup in `#apInterest` if `.val` is less than 0 or greater than 99.99 trigger an error.. else check `ul#mylist` if it has any `li`, if not `.hide`

on keyup in `#apPayment` if `.val` is less than 0 trigger an error else check the list for `li` hide if not.

`#apPrincipal` is the same thing exactly as `#apPayment`

what I have right this moment

```
$('#apInterest').live("keyup", function(e) {
var parent = $('.inter').parents("ul:first");
if ($('#apInterest').val() < 0 || $('#apInterest').val() > 99.99) {
    $('.inter').remove();
    $('#mylist').append('<li class="inter">Interest Rate cannot be below 0 or above 99.99</li>');
    $('#popuperrors').show();
    $(this).addClass('error');
} else {
    $(this).removeClass('error');
    $('.inter').remove();
    alert(parent.children().text);
    if (parent.children().length == 0){
        $('#popuperrors').hide();
    }
}
});
```

Although I have also tried

```
if ($("#mylist :not(:contains(li))") ){
$('#popuperrors').hide();
}
```

I had a function similar to this for all 3 textboxes but none of what I have tried seems to work..  any ideas on how to complete this

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery if div id has children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526873/jquery-if-div-id-has-children)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
if ($('#mylist li').length == 0) ...
```

Comment: This is a common and easy-to-understand mistake on Justin's part. `$("#mylist :not(:contains(li))")` will never be null; it will always produce a jQuery object, even if the selector matched nothing.  Testing the length of the object like this is the way to go.

Comment: you are better off comparing $('#mylist li').length === 0 like this

Answer (score 8):

I like using the `children()` method because it reads nicely and it works even if you've already cached the selector for your ul. Here's what it looks like:

```
$myList = $('#myList')
if ( $myList.children().length === 0 ) ...
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery always returns an array of elements. If no matches were found, the array will be empty. An empty array in Javascript evaluates to true:

```
console.log( !![] ); // logs: true
```

You want to check the length of the returned set:

```
if ( ! $("#mylist li").length ){
   $('#popuperrors').hide();
}
```