# check if a "div" contains other elements

Tags: jquery

I'm building dynamically an `UL > LI > a` structure, I want to check if on click event there are many other nodes.

I try this:

```
jQuery('ul.sub-menu li a').click(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).has('.sub-menu').length > 0)
        return false;
});
```

but doesn't work!

Comment: There is a previous question about doing x if a div has children, check it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526873/jquery-if-div-id-has-children

Comment: *I want to check if on click event there are many other nodes*: What do you want to check? Which *other* nodes? How many is many? Which relation do these nodes have with the clicked one? What is your HTML structure? Your question cannot be answered because your intend is not clear. *Edit:* Regarding your edit: "doesn't work" is a meaningless error description, which does not help.

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a question. Do your own debugging!

Comment: @Ramengo Yes, i try with "children" property but still not work!
`if ( jQuery('.sub-menu li a').children().length > 0 ) {
     //do something
 }`

Comment: Might be related to the fact that you are checking a class rather than a specific div id. Assign an ID to the div and try using that #id to evaluate the same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery('ul.sub-menu li a').click(function(){ 
  var has_other_sub_menu = jQuery(this).closest('.sub-menu').siblings().length > 0;
});
```