# How to check if an element is empty using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-manipulation

I want to call a function only if HTML of a `td` is empty (like `td` with `contenteditable='true'`), using jQuery.
**Note** that you should **not consider line breaks and spaces**.
How can i do something only if

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        <br type="_moz"></br>
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="false">2</td>
      <td contenteditable="false">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable="false">4</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        <br type="_moz"></br>
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        <br type="_moz"></br>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

None of the belows works :

```
if ($('#element').is(':empty')){
  //do something
}
```

or

```
if($.trim($("selector").html())=='')
```

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate post. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526873/jquery-if-div-id-has-children)

Comment: No it's not, **Note that you should not consider line breaks and spaces**. @louisdeb

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if input file is empty in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793880/how-to-check-if-input-file-is-empty-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)** method

```
$('td').filter(function() {
  return $.trim($(this).text()).length == 0;
})
```

```js
$('td').filter(function() {
  return $.trim($(this).text()).length == 0;
}).css('border', '1px solid red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        <br type="_moz">
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="false">2</td>
      <td contenteditable="false">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable="false">4</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        <br type="_moz">
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        <br type="_moz">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is this return an array of empty cells ?

Comment: @MMKY : jQuery object of empty cells, if you want as array use `get()` method

Comment: I reached my goal using `if(emptyObj.length != 0)` { // do sth }

Answer (score 0):

One more..

```
$('td').each(function() {
  if(!$(this).text().trim().length){
      $(this).css('border', '1px solid black');
  }
});
```

```js
$('td').each(function() {
  if(!$(this).text().trim().length){
      $(this).css('border', '1px solid black');
  }
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td contenteditable="true">
            <br type="_moz">
          </td>
          <td contenteditable="false">2</td>
          <td contenteditable="false">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td contenteditable="false">4</td>
          <td contenteditable="true">
            <br type="_moz">
          </td>
          <td contenteditable="true">
            <br type="_moz">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: What's the difference ? is it duplicate answer ?

Comment: @MMKY of course i used the legend but modified by mine.