# remove some elements if no children

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to remove some elements if no children...

this will work...

```
$$('*').each(function() {
    ($$(this).text().trim() === '') && $$(this).remove()
});
```

but it will look for all elements... i need to limit to some elements.. so i made this..

```
elements.forEach(element => {
    $$(element).each(function() {
        ($$(this).text().trim() === '') && $$(this).remove()
    });
})
```

but it doesn't work..

Comment: Whats `$$`? and if you wish to check for children, why check `.text()`?

Comment: **I need to limit to some elements** what is LIMIT ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery if div id has children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526873/jquery-if-div-id-has-children)

Comment: I have rolled back all edits. `$$` is used consistently, so it cannot be a typo. We should wait for clarity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:empty` pseudo selector to collect all the empty elements:

```
$(':empty').remove(); // removes all the empty elements
```

If you target some specific elements then either give it a class name and use both in conjuction:

```
$('.theClass:empty').remove();
```

Or just use the ***tagnames*** of specific elements:

```
$('div:empty').remove(); // removes all the empty divs
```

Comment: thank Youu i can use dis elements.forEach(element => $(`${element}:empty`).remove())

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `id`, `class`or `tag` in the `jQuery` selector. Try the following way:

```js
$("div:empty").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div><span>test</span></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Mamun's approach. If you want to apply it on a certain collection of element types only you could modify/simplify it as such:

```
$("div,td,p,... and other elements").filter(":empty").remove();
```

Sorry, just noticed, that Jay also provided a part of my solution. I did not want to repeat things unecessarily here, but maybe the combination of the two is still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

> Remove all `empty tags` from current document

```
$("*:empty").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you asked, you should rty :

```
if($("some selection").children() === undefined){
//do something
}
```

or as a function :

```
function rmIfNoChild(jQobj){
    if(jQobj.children() === undefined){
      //do something
    }
}
```